# Given a list of letters, finding all possible words in a ternary search tree

Tags: python, ternary-search-tree

I wrote a program to find all possible words with a list of given letters in a ternary search tree. The output is a sorted set of all words. Following is the python code for finding the words:

```
def _find_words(self, node: Node, letters: str, buffer=''):
    if node is None:
        return
    for c in letters:
        if node.key < c:
            self._find_words(node.high, letters, '')
        elif node.key > c:
            self._find_words(node.low, letters, '')
        else:
            buffer += node.key
            if node.isEnd:
                self.words.add(buffer)
                self._find_words(node.equal, 
                                letters.replace(node.key, '', 1), buffer)
```

The tree contains the following words: cat, acts, act, actor, at, bug, cats, up, actors, upper

I get the following output for the letters 'abugpscort':

`['acts', 'cats', 'cat', 'act', 'bug', 'ors', 'up', 'or', 't']`

whereas the output should be:

`['actors', 'actor', 'acts', 'cats', 'cat', 'act', 'bug', 'up', 'at']`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest not modifying the `letters` variable while you iterate over it. Since you are removing characters, you are most likely skipping certain values

Comment: I find weird that in your algorithm both `key < c` and `key > c` cases do not depend of c or key. Aren't these two explorations supposed to be before and after the for loop, to add words in the buffer in the right order ? Just a thought, I'm not really sure I fully grasp how your algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: I have found the solution. @ArthurHavlicek You're right. The for loop and the comparisons were unnecessary. I moved the explorations outside and with a little modification of the above code, it works fine now.

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not change the letters variable. When I put the argument as `letters.replace(node.key, '', 1)` it creates a new copy of the letters variable and replace the character in the copy. This is necessary to ensure that the number of any character in a word do not exceed the number of times it occurs in the letters variable. For e.g. if the tree contains "tools" and I input "lot", the program should return an empty set, which otherwise returns {'tool'} without the above bit of code.

Comment: Ah, okay. Wasn't actually sure if that method made a new copy or directly modified the variable